# java and air integration ,the error is "3214 NativeProcessStartupInfo.executable does not specify a valid executable file. " on Windows machine

Tags: java, air

Below is my JavaProcess.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        protected var process:NativeProcess;


        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var info:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();// holds all info about native process 
            info.executable = new File("C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.6.0_22/bin"); // unix "/usr/bin/java"
            //window program files/java

            info.workingDirectory= File.applicationDirectory;
            var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            args.push("-cp","../bin","net.riaspace.Main");
            info.arguments = args;
            process = new NativeProcess();
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA,onDataOutput);
            // this method will be fired when anything comes from java
            process.start(info);
        }

        private function onDataOutput(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            var message:String = process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
            Alert.show(message);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button label="call java" click="process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes('hello\n')"/> 


</s:WindowedApplication>
```

And My Main.Java is

```
package net.riaspace;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String input;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(scanner.hasNext("Hello|stop"))
        {
            input = scanner.next();
            if(input.equals("hello"))
            {
                System.out.println("Hello Flex");
            }
            else if(input.equals("stop"))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Jim Garrison , I saw you edited the post, can I know what exactly you edited in code pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an open source project " Flerry " to integrate Flex and Java Integration

Below is the link , it works for me.

http://www.riaspace.com/tag/java/

Answer (score 1):

> `NativeProcessStartupInfo.info` The
>   File object that references an
>   executable on the host operating
>   system. This should be the **full path
>   to the executable** including any
>   extension required.

It looks like you are missing a reference to your .exe file.

Comment: I tried code after changing the path with .exe , but some how my code is not being recognized...